# Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::fetch()

Tags: php, sqlite, fetch

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

 <?php
 class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('Users.db');
    }
}

$db = new MyDB();


 $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 $email_address =($email_address);
 $password =($password);

 $email_address = intval($_POST["email_address"]);
 $password = intval($_POST["password"]);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address='$email_address' AND password='$password WHERE email_address=? AND where password=?'";


 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $email_address);
 $stmt->bindParam(2, $password);

 $stmt->execute();

 while($column = $stmt->fetch())
 {
     echo $column["email_address"];
     echo $column["password"];
 };


 if($email_address==1){
     echo "<h1>Logged In</h1>";
 }else
 { 

     echo " <h2> Not Logged In </h2>";

 }
```

the line while($column = $stmt->fetch()) is throwing an error saying  Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::fetch(). anyone have any idea on how to resolve this situation? All i want to do is a simple log in page where i check against a SQLite database if the username and password is in the database.

Comment: there is a typo i your sql statement. move the latest  quote to password='$password'

Answer (score -1):

`$stmt->execute()` returns a resultset from which you can fetch rows:

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    echo $row['email_address'];
}
```